# How to write to a file using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm trying to write out some html to a file as follows but I keep getting an error:

```
var date = new Date(), year = date.getFullYear(), month = date.getMonth() + 1, day = date.getDate(); 

var folderName = year + '-' + month + '-' + day; 

var path = "public/" + folderName; 

fs.ensureDir(path).then(() => { 

console.log('success!') }).
catch(err => { console.error(err) }) 

path = path + '/' + date.getTime() + ".html"; 

let html = await page.evaluate(() => 
document.body.innerHTML); 

require('fs').write(path, html, "w");
```

The error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: First argument must be
>   file descriptor
>       at Object.fs.write

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`fs.writeFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) instead of [`fs.write()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback).

Note that if there is a file present with the same name it will be replaced with the new one. But given your naming convention this should never happen.

Answer (score 1):

looking at your example, you should us fs.writeFile:

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('YOUR_PATH', 'YOUR_HTML_TEXT', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err); 
  }

  console.log('file created');
});
```

Just to add more info, the function you were trying to use:

```
fs.write(fd, string[, position[, encoding]], callback)
```

Expects a file descriptor, this is an identifier returned for example by method open:

```
fs.open(path, flags[, mode], callback)
```